# Trekking solo in South Africa

Tags: safety, trekking, emergencies, solo-trekking, theft

This is an almost similar question to this one: [Trekking solo in Western Ghats, India](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/trekking-solo-in-western-ghats-india)

I have read a few blogs about people and their solo trekking experiences. At the first glance at it, 'whether to trek solo or not' sounds like an opinion based thing, but I wonder if there are any valid sources advising about whether to go or not. I am planning for a trek around Cape Town, South Africa (The Arangieskop hiking trail). I have an ample amount of experience in trekking, and I am in the process of grabbing essential knowledge about the route that I am planning to take.

However, assuming that I will have all the required information regarding the route and wildlife when I set off, I still lack any information on issues like:

- Exit point in case of emergency.
- Reports of Local threats like.
  plundering, thefts and safety of individual women.
- Threat from any sort of organized and/or unorganized crime (This is one of the reasons  I was denied to travel alone from Kathmandu to Lukla by possible public transport)
- Threats due to racism (I am an Indian)
- Local language barriers. (I know English, only)

Comment: What happened when you were denied travel from Kathmandu to Lukla? How can un/organized crime affect flights?

Comment: @Eyal: Sorry for being so late with the reply. I wasn't gonna fly from Kathmandu to Lukla. Planned to hike down the distance. Cost Cutting, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general trekking/hiking is not very common in RSA and most of the possibilities will be maintained by the [MCSA](http://mcsacapetown.co.za). I recommend that you get in contact with the Cape Town section of the MCSA and ask about longer hiking trips.

Generally you have to consider that most land in RSA is private property and owners may not allow trespassing. But if the MCSA tells you about routes this may be no issue because they should have an agreement with the land owners.

Crime is definitely an issue in RSA. A huge number of South Africans belong to the poor and if you show your wealth around, someone may help you getting rid of it. These people will hardly understand why someone hikes through their country, wearing/carrying all the sophisticated outdoor stuff which they never will be able to buy. Of course you won't meet as much people as in the cities but you have to be aware of this. A good way to deal with this issue would be to never do a hike on your own. Always go in groups or join organized trips.

At the end one little story. We wanted to hike to the top of the cable car in Hartbeestpoort but the officials (employees at the cable way station) denied access although we knew that there is a trail and it would be possible for us to reach the summit in about 2 hours. So you really need to be well prepared when hiking in RSA.