# Biking from Whitehorse to Vancouver

Tags: camping, canada, biking

I'm planning to travel along the Alaskan highway this summer (end of June until mid July). I'm not an extremely experienced camper and have only once spent a night outside of a camping ground so far. My greatest bike ride so far was from Zürich to Bern (145km/90m) which I managed in a single day, so I expect to be able to do around 80-100 km each day. So I think I should be able to make it to Vancouver in less than a month. I've read a handful of blogs from people who did it, so the idea isn't quite as outlandish as it first seemed. I'm mostly looking for information about camping spots, emergency situations, necessary equipment, further sources of information and just general tips and tricks. Here's what I've planned so far:

1 CHF = 0.98 USD

- Fly from Basel to Whitehorse and from Vancouver to Basel - totaling at around 1500CHF (including bike).
- I plan to spend around 1000CHF for the entire trip (25k total).
- I have a city/mountain bike hybrid that is made to be easy to fix.
- I plan to carry around 3-4kg in a backpack and maybe 4-5 in saddlebags.
- I think I'll only pack as much food as necessary and stock up along the way.
- I should be able to reach some form of settlement every 2 days.
- I speak fluent English and some French.
- The Temperatures seam pretty bearable at 11° degrees in July.
- I'm going to be alone.
- I'm planning to sleep in a tent most of the times.
- I'll probably stay as close to the road as possible.

Here're some of the stuff I am worried about:

- Is there a better Forum for trips like this?
- Wild animals (bears, buffaloes, elk), which precautions are necessary? Are they known to attack unprotected travelers? Do they keep off the road?
- Are the prices somewhat reasonable? In Switzerland you get robbed along the highways.
- Is the road kept in shape for bikers? Do I have to watch out for reckless drivers?
- Is there a danger of highway robbery?
- How quick do emergency services respond?
- Is camping along the highway even legal? Alternatively, are there enough camping grounds? Online research has been inconclusive.
- Is it even safe to travel alone, or should I look for a friend to join me?
- Is there cellphone coverage up there? Is there a way to get Internet?
- These are just some of the worries of the top of my head, I'm sure there are more.

So are there people who have done similar things? I'd love to get in contact. Where should I look for more Information? I'm mainly looking for the exercise and some scenery. Canada seams to most suited for this, but if there are other places for a novice I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to the Great Outdoors. This is cross posted from TSE, and I think it does not fit on either as it is posted now, too many sub-questions and several of them opinion based rather than fact.

Comment: Check maps.google.com bicycle route.  Lots of town and camp sites.  Robbery can happen but not something I would worry about.  Worse animal is flies and mosquitoes.    Carry bear spay and hang your food.  Personally if I was on a budget there are a lot of places in Europe I would pick before.

Comment: such as? I'm looking for a reasonably remote trip, but with a similar distance and I'd like to be able to camp in the wild if possible

Comment: Some of the questions would be better suited to bicycles.se, and in fact may already be answered there. In any case this is to much to address in a single question.

Comment: @ChrisH and willeke, the sub questions on wild animals in Alaska, the emergency services response time, the condition of the roads and the legality of camping all make sense for TGO. These could still be answered here.

Comment: @ShemSeger, you are the closest one who could answer this (since you are a canadian) :D Have a look at this question.

Comment: @Ricketyship I don't disagree, but I note that you also use *questions* plural. This needs to be broken down into several questions to work here.

Comment: @ChrisH actually, if we were to merge it into a - "what safety and transport factors do I need to consider for a blah blah trip", then it would make sense to add these sub questions as answers. Something like this - https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/trekking-solo-in-western-ghats-india/4855#4855

Comment: Just too long with too many questions.  Someone also mentioned it was cross-posted.  Closing and moving on.